# Floating point rounding errors in Knockout.Validation

Tags: javascript, floating-accuracy, knockout-validation

I have an numeric input with a step of 0.01 that is "watched" by Knockout and has the Knockout.validation plugin also checking the value.

When testing the input to make sure that it is giving appropriate error messages, I found that certain input will result in a validation message.  For example, the value -0.14 will result in the error: "The value must increment by 0.01".

The offending Knockout.Validation code is:

```
return utils.isEmptyVal(val) || (val * 100) % (step * 100) === 0;
```

For `val = -0.14` with `step = 0.01`, floating point arithmetic causes this line to return false, meaning that Knockout.Validation sees `-0.14` as an invalid input.  This is just an example, there are many cases where this happens.  For the `-0.14` case, the result of `(val * 100) % (step * 100)` is `-1.7763568394002505e-15`.

Is there an easy way I can patch this code?  Would the following suffice under all circumstances:

```
return utils.isEmptyVal(val) || parseInt(val * 100) % parseInt(step * 100) === 0;
```

Or should I have a range check?

Comment: Your fix would also allow `step = 0.011`. Is that a problem?

Comment: The step wouldn't change, and I believe that Knockout.Validation didn't support more than 2 decimal places before (by just looking at the code).

Comment: Did you get a value for the floating point error? Testing against a reasonable *epsilon* might be enough: `Math.abs((val * 100) % (step * 100)) < 0.000001` (or thereabouts). It needs `abs` because your argument may be negative.

Comment: When does val get casted to a float? Is there any way of accessing the raw user input?

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation, I found the code in [this issue](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/issues/395) fixed my problem.

The core code in question seems very similar to your proposed solution, although I assume there is a good reason to use parseFloat rather than parseInt.